# Catching the output of a console app in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stdout

I have a simple console app providing me with some pre-build functionality in Visual Studio 2010. It goes on to spawn other child processes (though waits for the termination of those child processes.

When I run the app outside visual studio all its messages, etc, appear in the console window (ie stdout).  However when I run this app under VS then I don't see any of the output in the build window.

Does anybody know why this is?

Its very annoying.

**Edit**: On further inspection I have managed to get the stdout of my app to appear but the stdout of the child processes are not appearing.  Any ideas?

I re-direct the stdout of the child processes using the following code:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
GetStartupInfo( &si );

si.dwFlags      = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdError    = GetStdHandle( STD_ERROR_HANDLE );
si.hStdInput    = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
si.hStdOutput   = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

// Create the process.
if ( !CreateProcess( applicationName.GetCStr(), cmd.CStr(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, workingDir.GetCStr(), &si, &pi ) )
{
    // Failed to create process!!
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't child processes automatically inherit their parents' standard I/O handles unless you say otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to make explicit handles for the child process to hook them up. MSDN has an article on it (or several), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for example.

Child processes inherit open object handles, but have their own stdin/stdout/etc. handles, unless you go through the proper hoops to create them explicitly for it. That's my understanding, anyway; read the article for more info.

Comment: Im simply going to accept this answer because I have realised that it IS working and I'm suffering another problem.  Thanks for the help though! :)